# Testing QuickBooks Web Connector

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, qbfc, qbwc

I've developed a Web Service in my software-as-a-service application for interacting with the Quickbooks Web Connector.

One of the things that I found during development was that different versions of QuickBooks have different versions of XML Schemas. So, the application was developed to be flexible enough to accomodate various schemas.

Two questions:
- Where are these fully documented?
- How do I test the various [selected] versions without purchasing and maintaining all of the various versions of QuickBooks?

Comment: Please add which particular versions of QB you are struggling with and perhaps some code to show what's going on and where things are falling down?

Answer (score 1):

> Where are these fully documented?

Yes. Look at the OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

There's a "Max SDK Version" slider at the top that let's you change what version you're targetting, and shows the documentation for that specific version.

> How do I test the various [selected] versions without purchasing and maintaining all of the various versions of QuickBooks?

Get the latest version of QuickBooks. Send it different qbXML headers when you send data via the Web Connector.